# From a given year to latest available year in R

Tags: r, import, package

I am using the R package to import data from Statistikbanken.dk.
For instance, consider the following code:

```
install.packages("danstat")
library(danstat)

user_input = list(list(code = "TRANSAKT",  values = NA),
                  list(code = "PRISENHED", values = NA),
                  list(code = "Tid",       values = NA))

data <- get_data(table_id = "NAH1", variables = user_input)
```

However, I only want data from 2000 to latest available. I know that 2020 is the latest available year, so I could do it like this:

```
user_input = list(list(code = "TRANSAKT",  values = NA),
                  list(code = "PRISENHED", values = NA),
                  list(code = "Tid",       values = 2000:2020))

data <- get_data(table_id = "NAH1", variables = user_input)
```

However, is it possible that the R program automatically take the latest year data. So next year I don't have to write 2000:2021.

Comment: Could you try to replace 2020 with lubridate::year(Sys.Date())? This might answer your question.

Comment: Seems like the package is not available at the moment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/danstat/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the **danstat** package to work on my R installation, but here is one way to get a sequence of years dynamically:

```
seq(2000, as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y")))
# [1] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
# [18] 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
```

Comment: Actually, I am not interested in the latest year, but the latest year where there is data in the specific table on Statistikbank.dk (that is actually 2020 for that specific table). But as you say, the package does not work anymore (I did't know that, since it work at my R). So I probably have to find a different way to get data from Statistikbanken.dk into R. :-)